# conda activate not working in a bash file

Tags: command-line, bash, anaconda, conda

I am trying to write a script with the name *myscrpt.sh*, so when I run it it automatically creates a virtual env and activate it using *conda*. My conda version is 4.7.1.

This is what I have at the beginning of my *myscrpt.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
conda create --name myenv1
conda activate myenv1
```

creating the environment is not a problem, however I get the error:

> ```
> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
> To initialize your shell, run
>
>     $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
>
> Currently supported shells are:
>   - bash
>   - fish
>   - tcsh
>   - xonsh
>   - zsh
>   - powershell
>
> See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
>
> IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
> ```

I don't get this error if I run `conda activate myenv1` directly in my terminal.

So far I have taken several measures such as using `conda init <SHELL_NAME>` which did not help at all. Then I added the following in my bashrc

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/<user>/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/<user>/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

which also didnt work. Next and according to [this link](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20) changed the path in the PATH line to:

```
. /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
```

This one was written for conda 4.4, but I was hoping wouold help me.

Then I tried `conda run` instead of `conda activate`, but this also did not help.

So any ideas how can I get this working? :)

UPDATE1: Now I use `source ./myscript.sh`, and activating works fine, but it gets to errors in `conda install`.

Comment: How do you run the script? `sh myscrpt.sh`?

Comment: now I do `source ./myscript.sh` and it solves the problem with activation. But the problem with `conda install` is now there!

Answer (score 4):

Either

1. Add `eval $(conda shell.bash hook)` to your script, or
2. Call your script with `bash -i` to invoke your interactive environment

Answer (score 3):

Another answer, given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438511/vscode-conda-activate-base-giving-commandnotfounderror) that worked for me on this error message was:

```
source activate base
```

So a full example could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
conda create --name myenv1
source activate base 
conda activate myenv1
```

Answer (score 0):

On *Ubuntu Focal*, this is the only method that working for me.

Assuming that your envs are installed in `~/miniconda3` directory.

```
source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate myenv
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but this worked :
in terminal Type:

```
$ bash
$ conda init
$ cd /path_that_include_env_dir
$ conda activate ./<env_name>
```

or

```
$ conda activate /env_path
```

"env_path" is full environment path as : /home/usr/env_dir

> To check environments list and their paths

```
$ conda env list
```